# QT - Modal Window with child windows

Tags: qt, modal-dialog

I am creating an interface where you are requested to login. If you do not have a user, you can create one with a register button. Upon pressing this button a modal registration window will pop-up. Now, this all works great, but, the registration has a pop-up calendar window for helping to select dates. How can I allow this child-calendar-widget to come above the modal window?

Comment: Now why did you rollback my edits? Any particular reason?

Comment: I did not feel that your edits provided much more than personal preference. I feel that the way my question is written is to the point and easily understood. For this reason, I would prefer it remain in its original form.

Comment: If anything my edits improved the readability of your question. Tags are not supposed to be part of the title. And there are minor issues with your punctuation and sentence structure which I corrected. But I won't get into an edit-war with you, so I'll let it be. You're free to disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a modal popup with the modal dialog as the parent, it should already be shown above the modal dialog.

You could, for example, put the calendar widget inside a `QDialog` with `Qt::Popup` window flag.